# How to find if values of an array are the keys of hash in Perl?

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have an array say @array. I would like to know which values of the array form the keys of a hash, say %hash. Is there is a simple way to do it other than using a for loop?

e.g.,

```
 @array = qw (a b c);   
 %hash = ( a => 1, b=> 2 );
```

In this case it should just output 'a' and 'b'.

Comment: You've got some bareword problems if you're using `use strict;` (and you should be).

Comment: Right.  If that array is supposed to contain the literal letters 'a', 'b', and 'c', it should be either `@array = ('a','b','c');` or `@array = qw(a b c);`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I use strict, I just didn't include it in the example.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This should do it:

```
my @array = qw(a b c) ;
my %hash = ( a => 1 , b => 2 ) ;

my @result = grep { exists $hash{$_} } @array ;
```